# How can I use Python Multiprocessing to change values in a list and return a list that shows the changed values?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I would like to create a Python program that is capable of utilizing the multiprocessing package to speed up reading and writing unto a specified list/array/collection.

The issue that I am running into is that the implementation of multiprocessing does not allow me write unto the list I am extracting values from. With some initial digging it seems that the arguments provided get cloned? Is there a way to force this implementation to reference the same list?

I've included code below that excludes the print statements:

```
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import get_context

list_of_files_1 = ['aa','aaba','aaaabb']
list_of_files_2 = ['aa','aaba','aaaabb']

def process(file_list,index):
    count = 0
    for i in file_list[index]:
        if i == 'a':
            count +=1
    file_list[index]=count
    print(f"Value in list @ index {index}: {file_list[index]}\t Memory: {id(file_list)}")
    
# Applying a 'serial' process:
for i in range(len(list_of_files_1)):
    process(list_of_files_1,i)

# Applying a 'parallel' process:
p = get_context("fork").Pool(processes=3)
for i in range(len(list_of_files_2)):
    p.apply(process,[list_of_files_2,i])
```

```
OUTPUT:
memory locations: file_1: 4410192704 file_2: 4438218048

Value in list @ index 0: 2   Memory Loc: 4410192704
Value in list @ index 1: 3   Memory Loc: 4410192704
Value in list @ index 2: 4   Memory Loc: 4410192704
New list of files before serial process:[2, 3, 4]

Value in list @ index 0: 2   Memory Loc: 4438530624
Value in list @ index 1: 3   Memory Loc: 4438327168
Value in list @ index 2: 4   Memory Loc: 4438405440
New list of files before serial process:['aa', 'aaba', 'aaaabb']
```

Comment: They CAN'T reference the same lists, because each process has its own separate memory space.  The usual way to do this is to use a `multiprocessing.queue`.  Have the processes feed their results into the queue, and have the mainline code read from the queue.  The queue module uses TCP sockets behind the scenes to send the data across.

Comment: _"Is there a way to force this implementation to reference the same list"_ not to state the obvious, but multiprocessing means _multiple processes_, as in multiple independent Python interpreter processes all running in their own memory space. You can't directly access objects in another process. You'd need to use some form of inter-process communication.

Comment: Could you comment on what the "reading and writing unto a specified list/array/collection" operation actually entails? That would help us suggest a good multiprocessing approach to suite it, or to identify if a different form of concurrency/parallelism would be better

Comment: @Brian61354270 the bigger picture.. and what I was hoping to accomplish would involve having a list (or a collection of file locations) that point to a particular file (in my case XML files and CSV files). A function would iterate through this list and return a parsed XML file or a parsed XML object. I've tried using the map method, but it takes longer that the serial method and eats up far too many resources.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I've found a simple workaround to my problem:
If using multiprocessing in Python, and you want to create a list that is shared among multiple processes, you have to use multiprocessing.shared_memory.ShareableList

Simply creating a new ShareableList object with the original list elements and passing that to the function did the trick:

```
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import get_context, Manager, shared_memory

list_of_files_1 = ['aa','aaba','aaaabb']
list_of_files_2 = ['aa','aaba','aaaabb']
l1 = shared_memory.ShareableList()

sl = shared_memory.ShareableList(list_of_files_2)
print(f"startList: {sl}\n")
def process(file_list,index):
    count = 0
    for i in file_list[index]:
        if i == 'a':
            count +=1
    file_list[index]=count
    print(f"Value in list @ index {index}: {file_list[index]}\t Memory: {id(file_list)}")
    print(f"Current List: {file_list}\n")

# Applying a 'parallel' process:
p = get_context("fork").Pool(processes=3)

for i in range(len(sl)):
    p.apply(process, [sl,i])

print(f"newList: {sl}")
```

```
OUTPUT:
startList: ShareableList(['aa', 'aaba', 'aaaabb'], name='psm_d8c0c06c')

Value in list @ index 0: 2   Memory: 4442739216
Current List: ShareableList([2, 'aaba', 'aaaabb'], name='psm_d8c0c06c')

Value in list @ index 1: 3   Memory: 4414932160
Current List: ShareableList([2, 3, 'aaaabb'], name='psm_d8c0c06c')

Value in list @ index 2: 4   Memory: 4414932160
Current List: ShareableList([2, 3, 4], name='psm_d8c0c06c')

newList: ShareableList([2, 3, 4], name='psm_d8c0c06c')
```